# Clang-Tidy: Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator

Tags: c++, c, gcc, bit-shift, clang-tidy

I want to split a `long long` (a 64-bit value) into two `int`s (32-bit each). For this I'm using the "standard way" of shifting the `long long` right by 32 to get the upper 32-bit and cast the `long long` to an int to get the lower 32-bit. However, [`clang-tidy`](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) reports the shift as warning:

> Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator

My code is the following:

```
void split_long_long(long long value, int &upper, int &lower) {
    upper = (int) (value >> 32); // <- Warning here at "value"
    lower = (int) value;
}
```

How would you rewrite this to avoid the warning?

Note that writing

```
void split_long_long(unsigned long long int value, unsigned int &upper, unsigned int &lower) {
    upper = (unsigned int) (value >> 32);
    lower = (unsigned int) value;
}
```

does not fix the warning either, even though there are only `unsigned` variables in use.

Comment: Alright, the following code no longer produces a warning:
`void split_long_long(unsigned long long int value, int &upper, int &lower) {
 upper = (int) (value >> 32u);
 lower = (int) value;
}`

Comment: Use unions - more readable and safe

Comment: There is no problem with the `unsigned` version you posted. What compiler switches did you use to generate a warning about that code? (Edit the question to show the compilation command)

Comment: @M.M: None in particular, `clang-tidy` is part of the code inspections in `CLion` IDE which are enabled by default: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion