# Proper modern way of converting two uint8_t into int16_t

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-shift, uint8t

What's the proper modern C++ way of converting two `uint8t`'s into one `int16_t` that would satisfy clang-tidy?

```
a[0] << 8 | a[1]
```

If `a[0] >= 128`, I want the result to wrap around, resulting in a negative value.

Clang-Tidy message is

```
Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator
```

Comment: Dunno what will satisfy clang-tidy, but you will want to cast `a[0]` to a `int16_t` *before* shifting it left, otherwise you end up shifting a `uint8_t` left 8 bits, and losing the bits.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Clang-Tidy says "Use of a signed integer operand with a binary bitwise operator"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - I could be mistaken, but the copy of the C++ standard says, `The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.` That kind of implies to me that the `a[0] << 8` doesn't lose bits, but instead gets promoted to something larger.  This is where I need a language lawyer to interpret, but a quick compile test shows this to be the case. But that could be undefined behavior meets conventional implementation.  Somebody help me out here.

Comment: @selbie And to what would a `uint8_t` be promoted? How does this fit with the Clang-Tidy message mentioned in the comments?

Comment: @vasily It seems to me that the exact message is too important for explaining the question to be left in the comments...

Comment: *Sheepishly suggests...* [`static_cast()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103512/why-use-static-castintx-instead-of-intx)?

Comment: See [Numeric promotions - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) (mid-page)

Comment: What is the expected result if `a[0] >= 128`?  A negative number?

Comment: `a[0] * 256 + a[1]` works just as well and generates identical executable code with modern compilers.

Comment: @L.F. yes, it looks that way in the datasheet.

Comment: By the way, @selbie, it seems like you are correct. ["Short types" seem to be promoted to ints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/10957435).

Comment: Also, [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582231/clang-tidy-use-of-a-signed-integer-operand-with-a-binary-bitwise-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I wouldn't call a duplicate. They seem to be in a slightly different situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to convert to a `uint16_t` (we'll talk about `int16_t` later)

```
constexpr std::uint16_t combine(std::uint8_t a, std::uint8_t b)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned>(a) << 8 | static_cast<unsigned>(b);
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rUpquSjx9s7JlPOk) in C++11)

One way to ensure portability is to first convert the `uint8_t` value to `unsigned int` to ensure predictable integer promotion.  The value is preserved regardless of the type aliased by `uint8_t`, because `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be capable of holding all nonnegative integers below 256, and the unsigned integer conversion rules guarantee that the value is preserved.  Then, the operations are guaranteed to operate on `unsigned int` instead of a signed integer type.

> **Question:** why convert to `unsigned`?  You are mixing types together.  Why not convert to `uint16_t` directly?

Note that using `static_cast<uint16_t>(a)` instead is *not a portable solution* because an `uint16_t` may still be promoted to `int` depending on the environment (for example, when `uint16_t` is `unsigned short` and `int` is 32 bits).  Converting to `unsigned` gives us full control over the integer promotion rules.

---

Now the OP want to convert this number to `int16_t`, resulting in a negative number if `a >= 128`.  You can be pretty sure you are using a two's complement system if you are actually intending to do this, so a simple `static_cast` may suffice.  Otherwise, you can use a separate check.  Again, a bit weird.

Comment: @Chipster Because `uint16_t` may be promoted to `int`.  Also, good question.

Comment: Sorry, just realized it's actually `int16_t`, not `uint16_t`. Either way, doesn't the OP need it in an `int16_t` anyway? Why promote it to an int? I must be missing something really obvious.

Comment: I don't understand why an _`uint16_t` may be promoted to an int_. This type is guaranteed to be unsigned if I don't make a mistake.

Comment: @Fareanor Suppose that `uint16_t` is `unsigned short` and `int` is 32 bits.  Then, per N3337 [\[conv.prom\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.prom#1), `unsigned short` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know that. But, it is very strange anyway, to change the type of an object arbitrarily like that. Do you have an idea about the reason of wrecking the types when they are prvalues ? It is a nonsense to me...

Comment: @Fareanor "C was designed to implicitly and silently change the integer types of the operands used in expressions. There exist several cases where the language forces the compiler to either change the operands to a larger type, or to change their signedness.

The rationale behind this is to prevent accidental overflows during arithmetic, but also to allow operands with different signedness to co-exist in the same expression ...

Comment: ... Unfortunately, the rules for implicit type promotion cause much more harm than good, to the point where they might be one of the biggest flaws in the C language. These rules are often not even known by the average C programmer and therefore causing all manner of very subtle bugs. " (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296)  C++ pretty much inherits these things from C.

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't know the existence of integral promotions. But to be sure, if you have declared a `uint16_t` and assigned to it the result of a `static_cast<uint16_t>`, as the receiver is `uint16_t`, is it correct if I say that it is sufficient to avoid integral promotion ? If not, it is very strange that even in C or C++ we lose control of what we handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197374/discussion-between-l-f-and-fareanor).

Comment: I can't join, my network access is restricted. But thanks for your explanations :)

Comment: @Fareanor Oh, really.  Yeah, integral promotions are only carried out when you do arithmetic. Passing the values around don't trigger integral promotion.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reassured then :) Sorry for the extra comments.